# How to convert a dictionary into an array

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, scikit-learn

I need to convert `labels_train` (which is a list of dictionaries `[{Id:0, Prediction:2},{Id:1, Prediction:4},....]`) for my classification model into an array.

```
#Classification model:
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
class_model = LogisticRegression()

#Fitting the classifier to the training set.
classifier= class_model.fit(X_train_pca, labels_train)
score= classifier.score(X_test_pca, labels_test)
print(score)
```

When I run this codeThank you very much :) I get this error:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: dict()>dict()
```

`X_train_pca` is an array therefore I thought that I should convert the lables_train also into an array but I don't know how to do it since an array is different from a list.

Comment: Provide the input, the expected output, decouple the problem and its nature from your actual code, tell us what you have tried and define "array" (i.e. numpy array or python list?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 class_model.fit(X_train_pca, [i['Prediction'] for i in labels_train])
```

Comment: This works! I've tried it out but in another context :-D